# Number of microstates for an ideal gas and its relation to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Considering the gas as the system, the gas particles are the building parts of it. Each gas particle has a certain value of position and momentum. For a single particle this set ( $\vec {r},\vec p$) represents a state in which the particle is. In the example I am studying the following things are assumed:

Diluted gas + Indistinguishable (identical) particles, that means nr. of micro states is: $\Omega = \frac{M^N} {N!}$,

where M is the number of states in which one particle can be, and N is the number of particles, and the relationship between them is that M>>N.

We assume that N is a constant value then : $\Omega = M^N$, which is the case for the nr. of microstates for N distinguishable particles, which can be in M different states.

This number (nr. of states ) is enormous.

The following commentary that I will highlight in bolt I don't understand:

**Why not an uncountable infinity of states? Quantum mechanics!(∆x∆p>ћ)**

Can anyone explain what does the uncertainty principle has to do here? Like, does it prevent infinity? And if so why? Basically why do we speak about the uncertainty here?